Understanding the proof of existence of nonforking extensions
In David Marker's book, Theorem 6.3.2 asserts the existence of nonforking extensions: For $p\in S_n(A)$ and $A\subseteq B$, there is $q\in S_n(B)$ a nonforking extension of $p$ i.e. RM($q$)=RM($p$).
In his proof, the argument is quite confusing to me: Let $\phi(\overline{v})\in p$ be of minimal Morley rank and degree with RM$(\phi)=\alpha$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an $\aleph_0$-saturated model containing $B$. Let $\psi(\overline{v})$ be an $\mathcal{L}_M$-formula such that $\psi(\mathbb{M})\subseteq\phi(\mathbb{M})$, RM$(\psi)=\alpha$, and $\text{deg}_\text{M}(\psi)=1$.
Let $q=\{\theta(\overline{v},\overline{b}):\theta\text{ is an }\mathcal{L}\text{-formula}, \overline{b}\in B, \text{ and RM}(\theta(\overline{v},\overline{b})\land\psi(\overline{v}))=\alpha\}$. Because RM$(\psi)=\alpha$, for any $\mathcal{L}_B$-formula $\chi(\overline{v})$ either $\chi\in q$ or $\neg\chi\in q$.
Because $\text{deg}_\text{M}(\psi)=1$ if $\chi_1,\chi_2\in q$, then $\chi_1\land\chi_2\in q$. In particular, for any $\chi(\overline{v})$, exactly one of $\chi$ and $\neg\chi$ is in $q$.
Firstly, what does "either...or..." mean in "either $\chi\in q$ or $\neg\chi\in q$"? Does it imply that at most one of the two holds, or at least one of the two holds?
Since it is easy to see that at most one of $\chi$ and $\neg\chi$ is in $q$ by $\text{deg}_\text{M}(\psi)=1$. I'd like to prove at least one of the two holds by $\text{RM}(\psi)=\alpha$.
Note that $\models \psi\leftrightarrow(\chi\lor\neg\chi)\land\psi$, so $\text{RM}(\psi)=\text{RM}((\chi\lor\neg\chi)\land\psi)=\text{RM}((\chi\land\psi)\lor(\neg\chi\land\psi))=\text{max}(\text{RM}(\chi\land\psi),\text{RM}(\neg\chi\land\psi))=\alpha$. Thus the claim is true.
If $\chi_1,\chi_2\in q$, suppose that $\chi_1\land\chi_1\notin q$ for contradiction. So by preious claim, $\neg(\chi_1\land\chi_2)\in q$. $\text{RM}((\neg(\chi_1\land\chi_2))\land\psi)=\text{RM}((\neg\chi_1\lor\neg\chi_2))\land\psi)=\text{RM}((\neg\chi_1\land\psi)\lor(\neg\chi_2\land\psi))=\alpha$. So at least one of $\neg\chi_1$ and $\neg\chi_2$ is in $q$, a contradiction.
Is my argument right? And what if "either...or..." means "at most"? Then what could the argument be like?

I don't really understand what you're asking, but you seem to understand correctly why both "at most one" and "at least one" hold (in other words, $q$ is a complete type over $B$).

The answer to the first question is that "either/or is meant in the sense that at least one of the two holds". That phrase doesn't ever mean "at most one of the two holds" in any context I can think of, though it also often means "exactly one of the two holds" (i.e. both at least and at most). As you've surmised, the fact that $RM(\psi)=\alpha$ is used in the proof of "at least" so that's what Marker means, and he later mentions $deg(\psi)=1$ to conclude "at most", as you did, and hence "exactly", which is the goal.
